# Compiling F# code on Ubuntu 12.04 using Monodevelop

Tags: .net, ubuntu, f#, mono, monodevelop

I followed the instructions [here](http://thecodedecanter.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/installing-monodevelop-3-with-fsharp-support-on-ubuntu/) for installing Monodevelop with F# support on Ubuntu, however when I open Monodevelop and try to compile a simple F# program I get the message:

> Error: Framework '.NETFramework 4.5' not installed.

If I manually compile on the command line using the same compiler Monodevelop is using (`/usr/bin/fsharpc`) the file compiles and produces an executable that runs just fine.  Why won't the project compile in Monodevelop and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked what framework is selected in the project options->Build->General?

Comment: That looks like it's probably causing the problem. It's set by default to `.NETFramework 4.5` but I can change it to `Mono/.NET 4.0` and then it compiles and runs. I still get a warning about the target framework but not enough to stop it from compiling an running. Thank you @Jester

Comment: Side note: framework 4.5 is available with Mono if you install newer version, that is 3.0 or higher.

Comment: @Jester: Looks like an answer to me...

Answer (score 1):

Officially (as of 2013) MonoDevelop/XamarinStudio doesn't support F# yet. So the F# support is not officially supported by Xamarin.

However you can use Visual Studio 2012 (or SharpDevelop) to build F# projects on **Windows** (targeting .NET Framework **3.0**), and then move the compiled binary to **Linux**.

I've tried this, and this solution is working.